# Cell Tower Location in Dell lattitude E7440 with sim card driver

Tags: c#, gps, geolocation, location

Im able to read the GPS location using windows API. But my requirement is to read the tower location from sim card as GPS always don't work inside rooms. Is there a solution I can talk to sim card and access cell tower location from C# code.

Note, this is not for phone, this is for laptop dell E7440 with sim slot.
Also Wifi / IP based solutions wont work for my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to get cell tower location from at least two options

- http://opencellid.org
- https://unwiredlabs.com

Both provide location information. `opencellid` is OpenSource. Below is sample code, you can refer the sites for more details

```
 e.g for unwiredlabs
 var settings = {
 "async": true,
  "crossDomain": true,
   "url": "https://us1.unwiredlabs.com/v2/process.php",
   "method": "POST",
   "headers": {},
   "processData": false,  
   "data": "{\"token\": \"your_API_token\",\"radio\": \"gsm\",\"mcc\"
    :         310,\"mnc\": 410,\"cells\": [{\"lac\": 7033,\"cid\":
    17811}],\"wifi\":     [{\"bssid\": \"00:17:c5:cd:ca:aa\",\"channel\": 
    11,\"frequency\": 2412,\"signal\": -51}, {\"bssid\": 
    \"d8:97:ba:c2:f0:5a\"}],\"address\": 1}"
    }
    $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
    console.log(response); 
    });
```

For opencellID
Getting cell position

Example

`http://opencellid.org/cell/get?key=xxx&mcc=260&mnc=2&lac=10250&cellid=26511
http://opencellid.org/cell/get?key=xxx&mcc=260&mnc=2&lac=10250&cellid=26511&radio=UMTS
http://opencellid.org/cell/get?key=xxx&mcc=260&mnc=2&lac=10250&cellid=26511&format=json`

Parameters
Headers
JSON:
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8

XML:
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=utf-8

Payload
key=apiKey&mcc=mcc&mnc=mnc&lac=lac&cellid=cellid &radio=radio&format=
format
Where
apiKey  string  API key assigned to the user
mcc integer Mobile country code
mnc integer Mobile network code or system identifier
lac integer Local area code, tracking area code or network id
cellid  integer Cell id or base station id
radio   You can specifiy GSM, UMTS, LTE or CDMA as the radio of returned cell. Otherwise first matched cell will be returned.
format  string  You can specifiy xml or json as output. 
Default is xml.

Answer (score -1):

No, you cannot, cell tower locations are only known by telephony providers and certain gubernamental organizatons (police as an example).

Without the exact location of each tower you cannot triangulate position, if you ask to the sim (if you were able to) it will only tell you which are nearby towers and it's signal strength, so it becomes impossible without knowing all the tower locations.

Comment: That's incorrect information. Cell Tower locations are available in crowdsourced data-sources like unwiredlabs.com or opencellid.org

Comment: Those services doesn't existed on 2014, the answer was right. Thanks for your downvote.